# Changing line size ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to change line thickness in R's `ggsurvplot`? I have tried several things, including using `size` (below), but nothing works. The lines stay intractably thick in my output and exported graphs.

The code I have thus far is very basic:

```
library(survminer)
fit <- survfit(Surv(Time, Outcome) ~ Predictor, Confounder, data = Mydata)
ggsurvplot(fit, size = 0.2, data = Mydata)
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I've down-voted your question because after posting a question we generally expect you to "hang around" to comment on questions/issues raised in comments and answers in a timely manner. Please keep in mind that you are asking others for their free time; you should make it as easy as possible for others to help you with your problem. Imagine calling your boss to ask for a pay-rise and then putting him on hold.

Comment: Seems as though closing this would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this has been a while but I had a similar issue and found that changing censor.size (which is the size of the censoring indicator) seemed to work. This can happen when there's lots of censoring, obscuring the line itself:

```
library(survminer)
fit <- survfit(Surv(Time, Outcome) ~ Predictor, Confounder, data = Mydata)
ggsurvplot(fit, censor.size=0.1, size = 0.2, data = Mydata)  ## Alt. set censor=FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm your issue. The `size` argument inside `ggsurvplot` works just fine:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, size = 0.1)
```

[image]

This is with `survival_2.42-6` and `survminer_0.4.3`.

Comment: Ok, I have survminer_0.4.3, but survival_2.43-3. Maybe if I update the survival package it will work.

Comment: @llsabang Your `survival` library seems to be more recent than the one I'm using, so I'm not sure if that is the issue. Also your `ggsurvplot::survminer` has the same version and this seems to be a plotting issue (rather than an issue with calculating the survival curves). Odd. So you cannot reproduce the plot I'm showing above (based on the `lung` sample data)? Can you confirm that you're still getting thick lines with the example I give?